Bug in GridDB code: Incorrect calculation results when querying data
I'm working on a project that utilizes GridDB, a high-performance NoSQL database optimized for IoT and big data applications. In my project, I'm implementing a feature that involves querying data from a GridDB database and performing calculations on it. However, I've encountered a bug where the calculated results are consistently lower than expected. The bug seems to occur only when processing data from specific rows in the database.
Code Snippet:
import griddb_python as griddb
def calculate_avg_temperature():
try:
# Connect to GridDB
    factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
    gridstore = factory.get_store(host="your_host", port=your_port, cluster_name="your_cluster", username="your_username", password="your_password")


# Get the specific container
    container = gridstore.get_container("temperature_data")
    
    # Query data and calculate average temperature
    query = container.query("SELECT AVG(temperature) FROM temperature_data WHERE sensor_id = ?")
    query.set_int(0, 12345)  # Assuming sensor ID 12345
    rs = query.fetch(False)
    
    # Process query result
    for row in rs:
        avg_temperature = row[0]
        print("Average temperature:", avg_temperature)
    
    # Close connection
    gridstore.close()
except griddb.GSException as e:
    print("Error:", e)
if __name__ == "__main__":
calculate_avg_temperature()

Expected Output:
The expected output should be the accurate average temperature calculated from the queried data.
Actual Output:
The actual output is consistently lower than the expected value, and this discrepancy occurs only with specific rows in the database.
Question:
What could be causing the discrepancy between the expected and actual calculation results when querying data from GridDB? How can I fix this bug to ensure accurate calculation results?
